# What does SSSZZ mean in date format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ?

Tags: date, datetime, elasticsearch

In [elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html), I have stumbled upon this datetime format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ
```

What does **SSSZZ** mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what it represnts:

1. SSS: This represents milli-second
2. Z : This represents UTC timezone (Zulu)